# How to abort a test method from continue running

Tags: c#, testing

Here is what I want

```
[TestMethod]
public static void T1()
{
    if (...)
        //continue the test
    else
        //abort the test from continueing.
}
```

I want to abort a test method from continueing if it fits specific conditions.

Comment: Can't you just use `Assert.IsTrue`?

Comment: Or oppositely Assert.Fail. However, if doing this, it's probably a sign that you are testing too much. It's particularly troubling when the *test* starts needing logic.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel May be I was not clearly present what I need. If just using hte Assert.IsTrue or Assert.IsFalse, I cannot tell whether the test pass/fail because of it actually pass/fail or because of the test environment issues.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use return statement

```
[TestMethod]
public static void T1()
{
    if (...)
    {
        //continue the test
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void T1()
    {
        if (...)
        //continue the test
        else
         {
          //abort the test from continueing.
         return; //this will do the trick
         }
    }
```